# Embulk: MySQL to S3 incremental update

Tags: java, mysql

I'd like to get some clarifications on how the incremental option on embulk works. When we set incremental to true and pass in the unique key to reference, where does embulk store the last record?

Each time I run embulk, is it able to pickup the changes from the previous run or do I need to re-define the last record setting each time I run embulk?

In addition, when I re-run embulk and there were no changes, does this reset the last record?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `embulk-input-mysql`?
Could you try `embulk run -c diff.yml config.yml`?
After the first run, it stores last_record data in `diff.yaml`.

Ref: https://github.com/embulk/embulk-input-jdbc/tree/master/embulk-input-jdbc#incremental-loading

P.S.
BTW, Could you create `embulk` tag? (I want to watch that tag)

Comment: Yes I am using embulk-input-mysql. Thank you! I'll try it out! I tried creating the tag but I'm a new contributor